# Difference between common method VS operator in Python data type as list

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods, attributes, operator-overloading

Here is an sample code, if I create a ListLike class as below

```
class ListLike:
    def __init__(self):
        self._items = []
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self._items, name)
```

I can use :

```
>>> a = ListLike() 
>>> a.append(2)
```

While cannot use :

```
>>> len(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object of type 'ListLike' has no len()
```

I am wondering what is the difference between **append** and **len** in this case , and when I create a class like this , how can I tell which methods/operator needs to be specified by myself in newly created class ?

Comment: @Aran-Fey, thank you !